# Does git reset --soft only change hash values?

Tags: git, git-reset

In this post the author does a good job of explaining the 3 options of git reset (soft, mixed, hard):
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-reset

He uses the "three trees" as a device to represent 1) working tree, 2) staging area, 3) "commit history/commit refs":

`--hard` resets (1),(2),(3);

`--mixed` resets (2) and (3);

`--soft` only changes (3).

It is what (3) actually represents I'm a bit unclear about. I can see how `git reset --soft` can be used to change which commit a branch points to. But I don't know why the word history is being used here. What exactly has been modified other than the commit which the branch and HEAD both references?

Edit: In particular does `git reset --soft <SHA1>` *only* edit i) the hash value inside `.git/refs/heads/master` file and ii) the hash value inside `.git/HEAD` and nothing else?

Comment: I think `.git/HEAD` does not even get modified, as it points to a branch, not directly to a commit. At least it did not in the few tests I just made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're asking about the concrete implementation—which I think is actually easier to explain anyway—take a look at what's actually in `.git/HEAD`, when you're on a branch:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
$ git checkout -b new
Switched to a new branch 'new'
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/new
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

So, as long as I'm "on a branch" as `git status` will say, the *name of the branch*—the full name of the reference, really—is in `.git/HEAD`.  So `.git/HEAD` does not change, and does not need to change.

Whether `.git/refs/heads/master` even exists is more problematic:

```
$ cat .git/refs/heads/master
cat: .git/refs/heads/master: No such file or directory
$ git rev-parse master
b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a
$ grep master .git/packed-refs
b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a refs/heads/master
b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a refs/remotes/origin/master
```

What has happened here is that Git has *packed* my ref names, so there's no longer a plain file: `refs/heads/master` is stored instead in `.git/packed-refs`, as one of several lines (the other matching line in this case is `refs/remotes/origin/master`).

That is, the reference-to-hash-ID map is stored in some *database*, not necessarily in a simple file.  (The packed-refs "database" is still pretty simple, though.)

To answer your ultimate question, though, it's just **yes**: `git reset --soft <hash>` writes `<hash>` into the name-to-hash-ID mapping.  This is true even if we use a name rather than a hash ID:

```
$ git checkout new
$ git reset --soft master~3
```

The name `new` now refers to the same commit hash ID that the name `master~3` refers to:

```
$ git rev-parse new
371820d5f1bb3c3e691ad21cee652c02c36ea758
$ git rev-parse master~3
371820d5f1bb3c3e691ad21cee652c02c36ea758
```

(The act of writing a new hash ID into the name `new` happens, in current versions of Git, to override the database of packed refs by writing the simple file `.git/refs/heads/new`, but you should not depend on this—use `git rev-parse` and `git update-ref` instead.)

Since I created `new` from `master`, above, this has merely had the effect of moving the name `new` back three first-parent hops (`master~3`).  That means that `new` is an ancestor of `master`, so:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
$ git branch -d new
Deleted branch new (was 371820d5f1).
```

... so Git is OK with simply deleting the name `new` now, as it's fully merged to `master`.

> But I don't know why the word history is being used here.

"History" is not really the best word.  To *really* understand this, read through the web site [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).  The key concept here is *reachability*.  Altering the commit hash ID stored under a branch name, as `git reset` does, changes the *set of reachable commits*.  If the set grows, more commits are reachable; if it shrinks, fewer commits are reachable; if it stays the same size, the same *number* of commits are reachable, but the set itself may or may not be the same.

"History" is, loosely and vaguely speaking, the set of commits in the repository, or the set of commits reachable from some name, or some subset of the commits reachable from some name.  Using some but not all of these loose definitions, moving a name changes history.

Answer (score 1):

> As writer wrote in topic, for understanding this you need to
>   understand git internals.

I'll try to explain same in best possible way.

In git commits are the linked list with reference of tree, which has references for blobs (files) and trees.

```
>    C1<------C2<--------C3
>     |        |          |
>     V        V          V
>     T1       T2         T3
>     |       / \         /\
>     V      /   v       /  \
>     B1 <--     B2 <---    B1'
```

As you can see above

- In commit 1 (i.e.) C1 has a file B1
- In C2, a new file B2 is added.
- In C3, B1 file is changed (B1') and a new snapshot of complete file is added in data structure.

What I have explained above is internal structure of git.

> GIT uses DAG (directed acyclic graph data structure)

Now branch, reset and checkout commands work on commit level only (as you can see commits form a linked list).

So suppose your branch is pointing to commit C2 and now you add a new commit C3 in same branch, so branch pointer will move from C2 to C3.

Similarly reset is opposite of commit, so when you do reset pointer moves to back commit from current commit. 
Say you are on commit C2 and you do reset you will move current branch pointer to previous commit.

Lets come to soft, hard and mix. Reset has 3 options

1. hard: Here the pointer is moved to previous commit and changes of previous commits are completely removed from working directory.
2. mixed: Here the pointer is moved to previous commit and changes of previous commits are maintained in working directory without staging/adding them, i.e. incase you run command

   > git reset --mixed HEAD~1
   >
   > git commit
   >
   > nothing to commit, working tree clean

   as you need to add/stage files using

> ```
> git add <filename>
> ```

3. soft: Here the pointer is moved to previous commit and changes of previous commits are maintained in working directory with added them, i.e. incase you run command

   > git reset --mixed HEAD~1
   >
   > git commit

it will create a new commit, as all changes were staged for commit.

Let me know if you have any questions. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way I think it could be reworded to be slightly clearer where you talk about `git reset` bringing the branch back a single commit as this is only the case if you provide the `HEAD~` argument (isn't it?)
What I am trying to convey in my question is this: _does `git reset --soft <SHA1>` **only** edit the hash value inside the .git/refs/heads/master file and the value inside .git/HEAD?_